# How would I edit a resource's attribute with name "xxxxx_id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a table with a column name of form xxxxxxx_id.  This isn't a key, it's a number that I want to be able to edit myself from the activeadmin console.

However, it seems that whenever a resource had an attribute with id in the name, it is excluded from the activeadmin console.  Removing id from the name resolves this issue, but I would still like to know if it's possible to make it an editable text field.

Comment: read this http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html, try something, show what you tried, if you tried this before, please put that in the question

Comment: my first guess would be to use `f.input :xxxxxx_id` as described in that link